# Installing Node.js to use in PHP application

Tags: php, node.js, npm, xampp, htdocs

I would like to use some NPM packages inside my PHP/Mysql applications xampp/htdocs folder but when I install it and run the command on CMD prompt, it installs the files elsewhere. How can I install them into the right folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a node_modules folder in your xampp/htdocs folder first.

If you just run install and there is no node_modules folder and no package.json file., the program recursively searches for a node_modules folder in the parent directories. You can auto-create the node_modules folder by using the flag `--save-dev` as part of the `npm install` command. If you intend on exporting/moving this project you should create a [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file and use that instead.

Also, be sure you are not using the `-g` flag as part of the install command as that will install the package in your global node_modules folder.